# Update manager notifications not getting in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, update-manager, kde, notification

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 .

Generally in Ubuntu with Ubuntu-desktop i can get desktop notifications if any new updates are available for the system. But i am not getting such type of updates in KDE. Is there any way to enable them in my PC  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Checklist**

1) Is the "Check for updates" enabled ?

```
kdesudo software-properties-kde
```

[image]

2) Is the System Notification for the updates enabled ?

KDE System Settings > Application and System Notifications > Manage Notifications; Event source: System Notification

[image]

At here: When those are enable the Kubuntu/KDE is checking the updates and notifying those.

[image]

**Q & A**

> August:   i don't have that option

Do you have the package: muon-notifier installed ?

> Description: update notifier for KDE
>   The Muon Notifier is an update
>   notification daemon for KDE. It uses the KDE  Daemon frame (KDED)
>   framework to present the user with update notifications,  providing an
>   opportunity to launch the Muon Updater to deal with these  updates.
>
> Homepage: https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/sysadmin/muon/

Comment: i don't have that option http://postimage.org/image/6o65mfg1b/

Comment: Nice answer - thanks for helping us really dig into this.  Like @raja, I also don't have a "system monitor" event source in that drop-down box.  But I do have muon-notifier installed.  FWIW I originally installed Ubuntu 14.04, then added KDE and switched to it.  I no longer see either any sort of upgrade notifications.  What else should I try?